# Filtering data between two times in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe imported from CSV with two columns (among others): Date and Time. Date is a date string of format `YYYY-MM-DD`, and Time is a string of format `HH:MM`. When importing this into pyspark with `inferSchema` "Date" is automatically inferred to datetime, which resolves them all to midnight (e.g. `2018-05-04 00:00:00.000`).

I need to filter the data to only data where the time is between two hours (9am and 5pm). The most basic idea I had was to filter purely on the string, e.g.

`return dataframe.filter(
        dataframe.Time.like("19%")
    )`

Alternatively, I thought of aggregating Date and Time into a single "Timestamp" column, such as below (probably quite badly, I'm still learning pyspark):

`data = data.withColumn(
      "Timestamp",
      to_utc_timestamp(concat(date_format(col("Date"), "YYYY-MM-dd "), col("Time")), "GMT")
    # )`

Basically, how can I do this, since I'm not thrilled by either of these methods? If the second method looks reasonable, how would one go about performing the filter? A disadvantage of the second method is that it leaves the dataframe with a new column, which is a potentially unforeseen side effect (I am trying to build this code quite modularly).

Thanks in advance. Apologies for the vagueness of the question, I'm still exploring pyspark and am trying to learn about the different possible ways of accomplishing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When importing this into pyspark with inferSchema "Date" is automatically inferred to datetime, which resolves them all to midnight (e.g. 2018-05-04 00:00:00.000)

for this you should use `date_format(col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` which will extract date from the datetime and convert the column to StringType

And now that both date and time are both is StringType you can use `concat_ws(' ', date_format(col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), col('Time'))` to concat both date and time

Now that both date and time are concatenated you can use `to_timestamp(concat_ws(' ', date_format(col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), col('Time')), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')` to convert the StringType dateTime to timestamp

and use hour function to extract the hour and finally use filter to filter the dataframe

so the working code would be as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.withColumn('hourOfDay', hour(to_timestamp(concat_ws(' ', date_format(col('Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), col('Time')), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')))\
        .filter((col('hourOfDay') >= lit(9)) & (col('hourOfDay') <= lit(17)))\
        .drop('hourOfDay')
```

which should give your filtered desired output

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Worked like a charm. Your code also has a lot of tricks that are good to know (e.g. using drop, multiple conditions). Very helpful, thanks!